# Using wc * to count the numer of lines of the files in the current directory

Tags: bash

When I use `wc  *` it shows warning for the directories.

Is it possible to filter the current directory and get only the list of files and pass it to the `wc`.

Comment: Yea sure.  Just use `find` or something to do the filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

Or with `gnu wc`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | wc --files0-from=- -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way with `find`:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec wc {} \;`

Comment: If you quote `{}`, it doesn't blow up when when there are spaces, newlines etc. in file names.